# Json - replace field name in generic Dto with associated type name

Tags: java, json, annotations

I have DTO class with Generics for data transfer

```
public class CreateDto<E> {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private E e;
}
```

My problem is while converting object to json using ObjectMapper, I am always getting json string as

`{id : 1, name : 2, e : {"state1":"value1" ...} };`

I want that e to be replaced with specific thing like, if it `CreateDto<Foo>` I want it `like a foo:{"state1":"value1" ..}`, when it is CreateDto it should be bar : `{"state2":"value2"..}`

I would like to know whether is there a way to get this using annotation or some other util.

Answer (score 0):

Thought, this is not the same way as you required, the same principal is to use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation at the property or method (getter or setter) level.

The following example (at property level);

```
public class CreateDto<E> {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    private E e;
    ...
}
```

will produce json string (e.g `Foo` for `E`)

```
{"id":"100","name":"john","e":{"type":"Foo","state1":"value1"...}}
```

Now it is distinct on the underlying type in generic data transfer object.